# How to know if an item is a leaf level item or not

Tags: qtreeview, qmodelindex

See the attached image below. I have created a tree view and I have connected the doubleClicked signal to a slot which prints the row number, column number, hasChildren and childCount

When I clicked on "Property 0", I got the first print and when I clicked on "222.1", I got the 2nd print as shown.

The first print is correct because Property 0 has 4 children

I was expecting the 2nd print also to be same. Why did it give me a childCount as 0?

**I wanted to know that when I clicked on any item in the 2nd column, whether that is leaf level item or not..**
**Please explain and help.**

[image]

Comment: I have tried doing the following and it works... Is this the right approach ? 
Basically, I get the parent index first and from that, get the cjhild at the 0th column which always gives me the correct hashildren and rowcount ? 
QModelIndex indexAtZerothColumn = index.model(row , 0 , index.parent())

Comment: If the index at 0th column has the correct information of the child count , then I am thinking why QT did not allow that same information to be available on the <n-th> column also ? 
Ideally, if there are no children of a row, then the same shud hold good even for the 0th col, or 1st col or any col